# Gson not populating List with gson.getJson

Tags: json, android-studio, gson, android-volley

I converting data to JSON and receiving it too. But something is missing. I don't know what. I have 2 links, 1 of it is working. It's receiving the response & converting data to JSON.

**I Tried:**
I replace the old database with new, but it did not work. Old database is working again. I check the table & column, but both are the same. What another thing I should try. Please Help!

```
 private void requestData(String uri) {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(uri,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Utils.psLog("Response > " + response);
                    try {
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        if (status.equals(jsonStatusSuccessString)) {
                            progressWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<PShopData>>() {
                            }.getType();

                            pShopDataList = gson.fromJson(response.getString("data"), listType);
                            if(pShopDataList != null ) {
                                Utils.psLog("Shop Count : "  + pShopDataList.size());
                                if (pShopDataList.size() > 1) {
                                    singleLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    updateDisplay();
                                } else {
                                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    singleLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    stopLoading();
                                    updateSingleDisplay();
                                }
                                updateGlobalCityList();
                            }
                        } else {
                            stopLoading();
                            Utils.psLog("Error in loading ShopList.");
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Utils.psErrorLogE("Error in loading ShopList.", e);
                        stopLoading();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Utils.psErrorLog("Error in loading", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError ex) {
                    progressWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    stopLoading();
                    try {
                        display_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        display_message.setText(connectionError);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Utils.psErrorLogE("Error in Connection Url.", e);
                    }
                }
            });

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            5000,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    request.setShouldCache(false);
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity()).addToRequestQueue(request);
}
```

I have tried debugging the code. Here is the screenshot. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfaLW.png)

**Here is the Logcat:**

> 07-05 21:20:38.130 20632-20644/com.logictex.usamapharmacy I/zygote:
>   Background concurrent copying GC freed 444(367KB) AllocSpace objects,
>   0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 1872KB/3MB, paused 7.903ms total
>   450.981ms 07-05 21:20:38.294 20632-20638/com.logictex.usamapharmacy I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=91KB, data=56KB 07-05
>   21:20:38.296 20632-20638/com.logictex.usamapharmacy I/zygote: After
>   code cache collection, code=91KB, data=45KB 07-05 21:20:38.557
>   20632-20632/com.logictex.usamapharmacy I/Choreographer: Skipped 99
>   frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main
>   thread. 07-05 21:20:38.621 20632-20673/com.logictex.usamapharmacy
>   D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5b3ffa0: ver 2 0 (tinfo
>   0xa5becec0) 07-05 21:20:38.627 20632-20812/com.logictex.usamapharmacy
>   E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error: 15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)  07-05
>   21:20:38.631 20632-20812/com.logictex.usamapharmacy I/chatty:
>   uid=10088(u0_a88) hwuiTask1 identical 3 lines 07-05 21:20:38.631
>   20632-20812/com.logictex.usamapharmacy E/StudioProfiler: JVMTI error:
>   15(JVMTI_ERROR_THREAD_NOT_ALIVE)  07-05 21:20:39.161
>   20632-20815/com.logictex.usamapharmacy I/FirebaseCrash: Sending
>   crashes 07-05 21:20:39.264 20632-20771/com.logictex.usamapharmacy
>   W/zygote: Verification of void
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$InputStreamTracker.(java.io.InputStream,
>   com.android.tools.profiler.support.network.HttpTracker$Connection)
>   took 135.766ms 07-05 21:20:40.671
>   20632-20791/com.logictex.usamapharmacy D/FirebaseInstanceId: topic
>   sync succeeded 07-05 21:20:40.732
>   20632-20638/com.logictex.usamapharmacy I/zygote: Do partial code cache
>   collection, code=122KB, data=85KB 07-05 21:20:40.738
>   20632-20638/com.logictex.usamapharmacy I/zygote: After code cache
>   collection, code=122KB, data=85KB
>       Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB 07-05 21:20:41.301 20632-20632/com.logictex.usamapharmacy D/TEAMPS: Response >
>   {"status":"success","data":[{"id":"1","name":"Medicines","description":"All
>   medicine of your
>   need.","phone":"","email":"","address":"","coordinate":"","lat":"0.000000","lng":"0.000000","paypal_email":"","paypal_environment":"","paypal_appid_live":"","paypal_merchantname":"","paypal_customerid":"","paypal_ipnurl":"","paypal_memo":"","bank_account":"","bank_name":"","bank_code":"","branch_code":"","swift_code":"","cod_email":"","stripe_publishable_key":"","stripe_secret_key":"","currency_symbol":"","currency_short_form":"","sender_email":"","added":"2018-03-24
>   09:06:38","status":"1","paypal_enabled":"0","stripe_enabled":"0","cod_enabled":"0","banktransfer_enabled":"0","item_count":132,"category_count":3,"sub_category_count":15,"follow_count":0,"cover_image_file":"unnamed.jpg","cover_image_width":"512","cover_image_height":"341","cover_image_description":"","categories":[{"id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Companies","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:47:51","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":"","sub_categories":[{"id":"1","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Abbott","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:53:09","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"Abbott.jpg","cover_image_width":"1910","cover_image_height":"1000"},{"id":"2","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Adam
>   Jee","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:53:39","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"3","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"AGP","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:53:59","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"4","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Amson","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:54:12","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"5","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Asian
>   Continental","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:54:26","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"6","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Atco","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:54:44","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"7","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Barrett","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:55:07","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"8","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Bayer","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:55:14","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"9","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Bosch","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:55:21","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"10","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Brooks","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:55:29","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"11","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Chiesi","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:55:54","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"12","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Don
>   Valley","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:56:02","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"13","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Ethical","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:56:11","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"14","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Excel Health Care","is_published":"1","ordering":"0","added":"2018-04-04
>   08:56:31","updated":null,"cover_image_file":"","cover_image_width":"","cover_image_height":""},{"id":"15","cat_id":"1","shop_id":"1","name":"Ferosons","is_published":"1","ordering" 07-05 21:20:42.369 20632-20632/com.logictex.usamapharmacy D/TEAMPS:
>   Error in loading 07-05 21:20:42.392
>   20632-20632/com.logictex.usamapharmacy D/TEAMPS: Line : 323 07-05
>   21:20:42.398 20632-20632/com.logictex.usamapharmacy D/TEAMPS: Class :
>   class java.lang.String 07-05 21:20:42.402
>   20632-20632/com.logictex.usamapharmacy I/Choreographer: Skipped 70
>   frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main
>   thread. 07-05 21:20:42.812 20632-20666/com.logictex.usamapharmacy
>   V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Comment: My old database is working. But when I replace the old database with new, it did not work. I check the table & column, but both are the same. What another thing I should try. Please Help!